# Background process to automatically kill unwanted popups

Tags: firefox

I am using the newest version of Firefox and I occasionally get a window that is displayed I don't wish.  As an example I get a full Firefox ( takes the whole screen ) that I have a virus and says unless I call a certain number my hard disk drive will be formatted.  The only way I can get rid of it is to reboot my Ubuntu 16.04.  Does anybody know of an application that will run in the background and kill this window automatically when it takes over my computer.

Comment: see DNS blacklisting and pi-hole

Answer (score 1):

Killing popups after they're displayed is too late, the right solution is to install an ad blocker.

Sometimes the ad blocker will let those popups through — ad and scam popup writers actively work to defeat ad blockers. In that case, you can *always* close the window. Even if the popup is somehow hard to close through your GUI, the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> (with that window selected, of course) usually works. Under Unity, moving the mouse to the top left of the screen (again, with the window selected) and clicking on the ⊗ icon should work. If you're desperate, you can run the `xkill` utility and click on the window.

There's no way to automatically kill unwanted windows because the computer can't know what windows you don't want. The computer can make a guess, based on rules written by the author of the program that makes the guess; programs that makes guesses of windows to avoid displaying are ad blockers.